# Change SSL Protocol error to custom error page in Caddy or either redirect to port 80

Tags: ssl, caddy, caddyfile

I am seeing SSL protocol error ( see pic below ) for domains which are not allowed in ask url for caddy.

[image: ssl protocol error]

Rather then ugly browser error i would like to show custom error page or either force backup self signed certificates. In case that is not possible i would like to redirect https to http port in caddy in case tls issuance fails in caddy.

Here is my excerpt of config :

```
    {

       cert_issuer  acme admin@example.com
       cert_issuer  zerossl ZEROSSLAPI
       cert_issuer  internal

    # Use Let's Encrypt or ZeroSSL to sign certificates.
log {
        output file /var/log/caddy/access.log
    }

        email admin@example.com
        
    storage redis {
        host          "127.0.0.1"
        port          6379
        address       "127.0.0.1:6379"
        username      ""
        password      "abc"
        db            1
        key_prefix    "caddytls"
        value_prefix  "caddy-storage-redis"
        timeout       5
        tls_enabled   "false"
        tls_insecure  "true"
    }

  on_demand_tls {
    ask https://www.example.com/abc-reg
    interval 2m
    burst 10
   }
}

https:// {

tls {
on_demand

}

@post method POST PUT OPTIONS
@get method GET

reverse_proxy @post example.example.com:80 {
        method POST
        header_up Host {http.request.host}
        header_up X-Real-IP {http.request.remote}
        header_up X-Forwarded-For {http.request.remote}
        header_up X-Forwarded-Port {http.request.port}
        header_up Access-Control-Allow-Origin {http.request.access_control_allow_origin}
        header_up Access-Control-Allow-Credentials {http.request.access_control_allow_credentials}
        header_up Access-Control-Max-Age {http.request.access_control_max_age}
        header_up Origin {http.request.origin}
}
reverse_proxy @post example.example.com:80 {
        method OPTIONS
        header_up Host {http.request.host}
        header_up X-Real-IP {http.request.remote}
        header_up X-Forwarded-For {http.request.remote}
        header_up X-Forwarded-Port {http.request.port}
        header_up Access-Control-Allow-Origin {http.request.access_control_allow_origin}
        header_up Access-Control-Allow-Credentials {http.request.access_control_allow_credentials}
        header_up Access-Control-Max-Age {http.request.access_control_max_age}
        header_up Origin {http.request.origin}
}
reverse_proxy @post example.example.com:80 {
        method PUT
        header_up Host {http.request.host}
        header_up X-Real-IP {http.request.remote}
        header_up X-Forwarded-For {http.request.remote}
        header_up X-Forwarded-Port {http.request.port}
        header_up Access-Control-Allow-Origin {http.request.access_control_allow_origin}
        header_up Access-Control-Allow-Credentials {http.request.access_control_allow_credentials}
        header_up Access-Control-Max-Age {http.request.access_control_max_age}
        header_up Origin {http.request.origin}
}
reverse_proxy @get http://localhost:6081 {
        method GET
        header_up Host {http.request.host}
        header_up X-Real-IP {http.request.remote}
        header_up X-Forwarded-For {http.request.remote}
        header_up X-Forwarded-Port {http.request.port}
 header_up Access-Control-Allow-Origin {http.request.access_control_allow_origin}
        header_up Access-Control-Allow-Credentials {http.request.access_control_allow_credentials}
        header_up Access-Control-Max-Age {http.request.access_control_max_age}
        header_up Origin {http.request.origin}
}
}
```

Help will be appreciated